# Design Issue: Service layer/ trying to maintain RESTful architecture

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, rest

I'm trying to design a web-application - and after doing a lot of reading on REST + design patterns, I'm at a loss on how to handle my requirements. I think I may be getting caught-up in all the design-patterns, but at the same time want to produce a well-architect-ed design.

I have 2 major business-objects, `Customer` and `Order`, with a *Has Many* relationship. Currently, I have no service layer, and the REST API is in the BL:

```
GET Customers                         GET Orders
GET Customers/id                      GET Orders/id
POST Customers                        POST Orders
PUT Customers/id                      PUT Orders/id
DELETE Customers/id                   DELETE Orders/id
```

But things become hard to design when I have to architect for legacy means of user-data input, and well as for the future:

- **Now:** Users upload an **Excel .xlsx** file containing Customer, Order information, which I parse, extract, create `Customer`/`Order` business-objects for, and perform validations. In order to have a pleasant User-experience, I don't save these objects right away, I return them to the User (along with any errors from the verifications) so they may make any needed changes before finally submitting them. (this 2-step submission just adverts the requirement of correcting sources of any validation errors directly in the Excel file).
- **Future:** Customer/Order data will be maintained, and uploaded, through a web service/platform.

I don't know how to handle these requirements gracefully, and intelligently. Is this a case where I need to expose a Service Layer that publishes an interface for the soon-to-be-legacy Excel-upload, as well as an interface for the web service?

Any design help would be appreciated, as I'm rather new to this type of development and rather not make a major architectural mistake that will come back to bite me later..

Thanks in advance.

**edited as comments suggest**

Comment: I don't have experience with this situation, so just a note: when the client knows the resource's ID (i.e. `Customers/id`, `Orders/id`), inserts/update should use `PUT` rather than `POST`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Comment: @MikePartridge: According to [this article](http://www.filecatalyst.com/rest-http-post-vs-http-put), idempotency is the determining factor.  I actually agree with the link you posted, which says that PUT is basically for upserts, while the effect of a POST is defined by the server and can basically be anything.  That would be consistent with idempotency, however; PUT is idempotent, POST is not.

Comment: Indeed. My earlier comment simplifies the topic, but I think my point follows from the idempotancy of `PUT`.

Comment: Why are you using a service anyway?

Comment: @EmmadKareem What do you mean? You mean the **Future** source of data input? We want to integrate with [SalesForce.com](http://www.salesforce.com/)

Comment: @EmmadKareem or do you mean why am I doing this as a web-application? That's what my employer requested. %100 web-based

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest path would be to create a RESTful interface around your business objects and then code a small service with the purpose of taking an spreadsheet, parsing it, and making the appropriate calls against your RESTful service.

No matter which route you take you will have to create the RESTful portion as well as the spreadsheet handling portion (or maybe that's already written). It only seems logical to code the spreadsheet portion against your final API. This will also give you an early peak into using your API and possibly point out some issues or shortcomings that were overlooked in the planning stages.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking of doing - just wanted some verification that it was a sensible thing to do